# Can't SEND attachments on Exchange 2013 OUTGOING emails

Tags: exchange

I have a fairly new installation of Exchange 2013 on Windows Server 2012 R2 on Hyper-V VM. 
I cannot seem to send any attachments other than text on any outbound emails. When I try, the email arrives with a short text file in place of the attachment, that says:

*The Attachment has been Removed.*

I thought attachment management was only for incoming emails. If this is due to some new security feature in Exchange 2013, is there a place in Exchange where I can turn it off, or configure it appropriately?

NOTE:  The attachments are generally `.exe`s or `.Zip`s, but I *always* add `.remove` or `.txt` at the end to eliminate the extension issue.

Comment: On Exchange try: Get-AttachmentFilterEntry and see what filters you have in place, if any.

Comment: The command `Get-AttachmentFilterEntry` is only available on edge server, and this is outgoing mail issue...

Answer (score 1):

Check the file extension. For several versions, Outlook or Exchange (I forget which exactly) will always strip out certain files like EXE, VBS, PS, BAT, etc.

Try a TXT file and see if the same thing happens.

If that isn't it, check the Transport Rules.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj674307(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: It is happening for a .Net compiled executable, which I have renamed so it is is `filename.exe.remove`.  No Transport rules are in effect. or, at least, none show in my ECP under `MailFlow, Rules`

Comment: An Attachment arrives but it is not the one I sent, it is simple text file that says "This attachment was removed."

Comment: Actual *.txt files (if they really only have ascii text in them) work ok.  It's just binary or non-text files that fail.